# Should I release a pointer that's pointing to an item in an array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Not quite sure how to phrase this, but should I release a variable in this situtation:

```
NSString *string = @"HELLO WORLD";
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:string];  
NSString *shouldIReleaseThis = [array objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@", shouldIReleaseThis);
//????  [shouldIReleaseThis release] ??????

//Do stuff with array
```

Should I release it? Why or why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't own it (you didn't get that reference from `new`, `alloc`, `retain` or `copy`), so you shouldn't release it. See Apple's [memory management programming guide](http://developer.euro.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) for a brief but complete overview of the memory management rules in Cocoa.

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I was looking for. I'd read about memory management, but somehow the concept of "ownership" hadn't really sunk in.

Comment: This is a really good answer that applies to all variable releasing in Cocoa. +1!